# Translate string in different language that is in database

Tags: android

Hello friends I have made an application in which I have fetched data from database.All data in my application is coming from database.I have made this application in English language but now I want to convert my application in Hindi and other languages too.Actually if I used XML for string then I make different string.xml for every language and then set locale it was not the issue but converting string in database and then fetch.so please suggest me how can I adopt this idea.Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- Add columns to your tables with the translations:

  TABLE messages : ID, CONTENT, CONTENT_FR, CONTENT_ES, ...

Then you select the column according to the locale set in the device (if locale is FR, then use the column CONTENT_FR, if the locale is something not yet provided by the app, fallback to the CONTENT column)

- Use several DB files (if your DB is static and won't be updated):

Load the DB file that corresponds to the user locale. Then your queries will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have db like

```
id, type, lang_id, str
```

- `id` - string id
- `type` - where this is used (1-login message, 2-error message, 3-character names, 4-attack names, etc.)
- `lang_id` - language id, you can use 2-digit code (EN-English, FR-French, DE-German, etc.) or your own id definition (1-English, 2-French, 3-German, etc.)
- `str` - the display string